# What's the font used in the game Return to Ravenhearst?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I am trying to find the font used in **Return to Ravenhearst** game. A screenshot of the text of which I am looking is:

[image: From: www.mobygames.com/images/shots/l/342975-mystery-case-files-return-to-ravenhearst-windows-screenshot.png]

I have tried WhatTheFont and similar services, but they are very sensitive.

Comment: Have you tried to [search by appearance](http://www.identifont.com/identify.html)? I've had good results with that, although it requires a sensible sample size.

Comment: You can have a look [HERE](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/30-free-handwriting-fonts-every-designer-should-own). The exact same one may not be there but very similar ones can probably be found.

Comment: Unable to find even a closing match. :(

Comment: @jensgram Search by appearance doesn't work. Just tried.

Comment: Handwritten fonts can be tricky to match if you don't already know what it is, because there are just so many of them. I browsed myfonts.com for awhile (picked the handwriting tag, entered some letters, and scrolled away!), but couldn't find anything. [This](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/madtype/casino-hand/) and [this](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/chank/skippy-sharp/) are at least somewhat in the same ballpark, but they're not the correct answer so I'm just posting as a comment.

Comment: Might even be a custom handwritten font, in which case you won't find it anywhere!

Comment: Sure. Lemme check it out @Brendan! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out the font. It is [Domestic Manners](http://www.dafont.com/domestic-manners.font). You can see the preview here. Thanks to [Matt_2.0](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/9447/matt-2-0). I was using this font too! :)

[image: preview]

Answer (score 2):

This is an actual font and I it is bugging me that I cannot remember it.  Also, this font would be considered as a handwritten font.  You can look through many font sites but look for specific characteristics.  In this case the Q, lowercase f, and lowercase g should work.

Some similar fonts I have found:

[Seriously](http://www.dafont.com/seriously.font?fpp=50&text=Qfg)

[image]

[Architect's Daughter](http://www.dafont.com/architects-daughter.font?fpp=50&text=Qfg)

[image]

[dafont search parameters](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=603&page=1&fpp=50&text=Qfg)

Comment: Architects Daughter is somewhat similar. Seriously, seriously not that matching. :P

Comment: Okay then. For now will accept the answer. I am planning to check out their source to find some font name at least... :)

Comment: The font is [Domestic Manners](http://www.dafont.com/domestic-manners.font).

Comment: Hey buddy, congrats on becoming a mod! I have found out that it is Domestic Manners. `:)`